# Problems with converting old Fortran code

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran

I downloaded Code::Blocks with the 2012 compiler (so that the compiler would not complain about “GO TO”), ran the code and it gave me a bunch of errors, most of which were related to lines 290-311. Tell me, please, how to fix them? I copied these lines from the book and corrected some errors by combining several lines into one.

Screenshots of code from the book: https://acrobat.adobe.com/id/urn:aaid:sc:VA6C2:e77e5821-8991-4144-9711-d2ffcf868c0a

Code: https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/ZkN

```
290!
291    1 FORMAT (20A4)
292    2 FORMAT (1H1,/,25X,20A4,/)
293    3 FORMAT (3I4)
294    4 FORMAT (F6.2,E11.4,2F12.4)
295    5 FORMAT (3E11.4)
296    6 FORMAT (/,109H NUMBER OF STRAIGHT-LINE SEGMENTS (EACH COUNTING AT LEAST ONE BOUNDARY ELEMENT) USED TO DEFINE BOUNDARIES =,I3,//,12 23H NUMBER OF STRAIGHT-LINE SEGMENTS USED TO SPECIFY OTHER LOCATIONS (I.E., NOT ON A BOUNDARY) WHERE RESULTS ARE TO BE FOUND =,I3)
297    7 FORMAT (/,32H NOSYMMETRY CONDITIONS IMPOSED.)
298    8 FORMAT (/,18H THE LINE X = XS =, F12.4,23H IS A LINE OF SYMMETRY.)
299    9 FORMAT (/,18H THE LINE Y = YS =, F12.4,23H IS A LINE OF SYMMETRY.)
300    10 FORMATE (/,19H THE LINES X = XS =,F12.4,13H AND Y = YS =, F12.4,23H ARE LINES OF SYMMETRY.)
301    11 FORMATE(/,18H POISSON'S RATIO =,F6.2,//,18H YOUNGS MODULUS =,E11.14)
302    12 FORMATE (/,31H XX-COMPONENT OF FIELD STRESS -,E11.4,//,31H YY-COMPONENT OF FIELD STRESS =,E11.4,//,31H XY COMPONENTOF FIELD STRESS =,E11.4)
303    13 FORMATE (1H1,/,27H BOUNDARY ELEMENT DATA.,//,96H ELEMENT KODE X (CENTER) Y (CENTER) LENGTH ANGLE US OR SIGMA-S UN OR SIGMA-N,/)
304    14 FORMATE (I4,4F12.4,I4,2E11.4)
305    15 FORMATE (2I9,3F12.4,F12.2,2E15.4)
306    16 FORMATE (1H1,/,66H DISPLACEMENTS AND STRESS AT MIDPOINTS OF BOUNDARY ELEMENTS.,//,40H ELEMENT UX UY US,60H UN SIGXX SIGYY SIGXY SIGMA-S SIGMA-N,10H SIGMA-T,/)
307    17 FORMATE (I10,4F10.6,6F10.1)
308    18 FORMATE (1H1,/,64H DISPLACEMENTS AND STRESSES AT SPECIFIED POINTS IN THE BODY.,//,93H POINT X CO-ORD Y CO-ORD UX UY SIGXX SIGYY SIGXY,/)
309    19 FORMATE (4F12.4,I4)
310    20 FORMATE (I9,2F12.4,2F12.6,3F12.1)
311!
```

Errors: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPXT3.png

Comment: It would be helpful if you could edit your question to include the relevant piece of code (as text, not a screenshot), and also include the error messages you're getting.

Comment: You need to fix the bad indentation, the incorrect spelling of FORMAT, and find a compiler which understands bits of the Fortran language which stopped being parts of the Fortran language 30 years ago, before you can start to think about using that code.

Comment: What compiler options are you using? "combining several lines into one" is a very bad thing to do in fixed-form source without politely asking the compiler to support the very long lines you have here.

Comment: How is this different from yesterday's post, which has been deleted due to a number of reasons?

Comment: Do not just delete closed post and ask again. You can be automatically banned. Deleted questions also count towards the potential ban and quite strongly.

Comment: And never put error messages into pictures. This is really important. Always copy and paste the error messages into the question as text. The error messages must be searchable so that people with a similar problem can find the question.

Comment: It is probably the FORMATE.  Try changing FORMATE to FORMAT